# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange](http://money.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://money.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Eh, bro - why are you still running? Seriously, do you see the date you posted this? Hint, IT'S ALMOST JULY NOW. We gotta have a talk when mom gets home, I think we might need to put you back on that medicine.

Answer (score 1):

On the whole, answers to the questions in the site self-evaluation are of reasonable quality.  However, they just don't rank high at all in Google searches — personal finance web resources are a very crowded space.

I've also noticed that some taxation questions now encroach on [Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxes) territory:

- [How can I claim tax back from whilst I was working in Austria?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/27394/how-can-i-claim-tax-back-from-whilst-i-was-working-in-austria)
- [I am not a U.S. citizen. What happens to my 401K if I have to go back to India?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/27080/i-am-not-a-u-s-citizen-what-happens-to-my-401k-if-i-have-to-go-back-to-india)

Comment: These are very on topic on this site. While there may be some overlap with "Expats", it doesn't mean that expats are barred from asking personal finance questions on Money.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove "personal" from the name of this site and call it simply "finance and money", and make it more useful to many people who have more general questions to the field, but not necessarily related to their personal situation or investment.

Comment: Disagree. See http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/1949/should-we-remove-the-money-part-from-the-site-name-and-logo-to-prevent-repe